# A common way to contribute copyrighted images?

Tags: graphics, packages, copyright

I'm writing a script about art & mathematics with a lot of pictures that I must contribute copyright.
I would not like to put the copyrights in the caption, is there a usual way to attribute copyright somewhere at the end? Perhaps a package that would do this automatically?

Comment: You might be interested in the `copyright` package: it defines a `\copyrightbox` command which  adds the copyright on a side of the image, in a grey font by default, independently of the caption.

Comment: In some books I have read (but can't now find) copyrights were noted in some kind of Acknowlegments section. I thought that you might have a bibliography saying where your pictures came from and the copyright information for them. I don't know how you might accomplish that.

Comment: @PeterWilson `biblatex` can handle that easily, with `type=`, `keyword=` and `category=` option settings, including `not...` versions, for the bibliography command; or a combination of those settings (`filter`) - amongst other things. `\defbibfilter{example}{%
( type=book or type=inbook )
and keyword=abc
and not keyword={x y z}
}` Categories work at document level and you can add items to a category mid-document as you need them and without changing anything in the .bib file.

Comment: copyright package seems good, I'll use that one. thanks.